# Python read char in text until whitespace

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a generator function that will read a word on request char by char from a text file. I'm aware of `.split()`, but I specifically need char by char until white space.

```
word = []
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    char = file.read(1)
    for char in file:
        if char != " ":
            word.append(char)
file.close()
print(word)
```

This code does not exactly do what I want :( I don't have much experience in programming...

EDIT: I have a code like this now:

```
def generator():
word = " "
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    file.read(1)
    for line in file:
        for char in line:
            if char != " ":
                word += char
return(word)


def main():
    print(generator())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And now it pretty much does what I want, it prints out the char one by one, but it does not stop after the whitespace " " and so prints out the whole text without any spaces. So how can I make it stop before the whitespace and jump put of the function?

Comment: Tip: don't use the same variable name `char` for the for loop and the `= file.read(1)`. Also, if you use a context manager (`with`) you don't have to close the file manually

Comment: What does the program print? And what did you expect it to print?

Comment: This line of code prints out lines from the text, but without the first char :P I want to print one word from the text, so in this case only the first word.

Comment: isnt char defined by `'` not `"`? If so, your WORD has to be `' '`

Comment: well to my knowledge there is no difference between ' and "

Comment: In python it doesn't matter if you use ' or " for strings

Answer (score 4):

The following demonstrates a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) function that yields the individual words from the file as delimited by white-space, reading but one character at a time:

```
def generator(path):
    word = ''
    with open(path) as file:
        while True:
            char = file.read(1)
            if char.isspace():
                if word:
                    yield word
                    word = ''
            elif char == '':
                if word:
                    yield word
                break
            else:
                word += char

# Instantiate the word generator.
words = generator('text.txt')

# Print the very first word.
print(next(words))

# Print the remaining words.
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

If the `text.txt` file contains:

```
First word on first line.
Second              line.

New paragraph.
```

then the above script outputs:

```
First
word
on
first
line.
Second
line.
New
paragraph.
```

It should be noted that the above `generator` function is unnecessarily complicated, due to the dubitable constraint that the file be read one character at a time. The much more "pythonic" implementation, `yield`ing the same results,  would be this:

```
def generator(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                yield word
```

Comment: The first generator is working fast and with a low memory footprint for a file containing very large lines, while the last one is simpler but slower on this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
for char in file:
```

This line reads a line not a character.

So you need to do something like this-

```
for line in file:
    for char in line:
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I think I also should rather create a string not a list, so something like this: 

word = ""
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    character = file.read(1)
    for line in file:
        for char in line:
            if char != " ":
                word += char
print(word)

But im still not getting what i need :( now i get still whole lines printed